# filling up an array in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am new to c++ . I was trying to write following code to fill up each byte of array with new values without overriding others. Each byte (r) below should be added up at new address of the array.

```cpp
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) {
    char y[80];
    for(int b = 0; b < 10; ++b) {
        strcpy_s(y, "r");
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is any function in c++ which can do that. In the above case the value 'r' is arbitrary and this can have any new value.
So the resultant array of characters should contain value rrrrr... 10 times.
Thanks a lot in advance for this.

Comment: If you are going to use C++, try to avoid standard C functions when there is a C++ alternative. `strcpy` is a C function, and `strcpy_s` is a proprietary extension and not portable.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using C++11

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    char array[80];
    std::fill(std::begin(array),std::begin(array)+10,'r');
}
```

Or, as mentioned in the comments you can use `std::fill(array,array+10,'r')`.

Comment: What's the point of the `std::begin`? You can simply use `array`.

Comment: @JackAidley Out of habit now :(

Comment: Out of idle interest, how does the performance of `std::fill` compare to memset?

Comment: @JackAidley compiling with -O2 and the ASM output is [near identical](http://pastebin.com/w5ge9MqH)

Comment: @JackAidley: Documented intent. `std::begin` is the "correct" tool to use here.

Comment: @Non-Stop: I strongly disagree, `std::begin` is pointlessly verbose. Worst, it suggests that work is being done that isn't. Anyone using C-style arrays should understand that `array` here points to the first element of the array.

Comment: @JackAidley: Disagreeing is certainly your right, even though you're wrong. :)

Comment: `begin()+10` is ugly, Use
`fill(begin(array),end(array),'r');`

Comment: @balki the original question was to fill the first 10 elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `[]` operator and assign a `char` value.

```
char y[80];
for(int b=0; b<10; ++b)
    y[b] = 'r';
```

And yes, `std::fill` is a more idiomatic and modern C++ way to do this, but you should know about the `[]` operator too!

Answer (score 2):

Option 1:
Initialize the array while defining. Convenient for initializing only a small number of values. Advantage is that the array can be declared `const` (not shown here).

```
char const fc = 'r';   // fill char
char y[ 80 ] = { fc, fc, fc, fc,
                 fc, fc, fc, fc,
                 fc, fc };
```

Option 2:
Classic C

```
memset( y, y+10, 'r' );
```

Option 3:
Classic (pre-C++11) C++

```
std::fill( y, y+10, 'r' );
```

Comment: [`char y[80] = "rrrrrrrrrr";`](http://codepad.org/lw9rVDXo)

Answer (score 1):

```
// ConsoleApp.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int fun(bool x,int y[],int length);
int funx(char y[]);
int functionx(bool IsMainProd, int MainProdId, int Addons[],int len);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int AddonCancel[10];

    for( int i = 0 ; i<4 ;++i)
    {
        std::fill(std::begin(AddonCancel)+i,std::begin(AddonCancel)+i+1,i*5);
    }
    bool IsMainProduct (false);
    int MainProduct =4 ; 
    functionx(IsMainProduct,MainProduct,AddonCancel,4);

}

int functionx(bool IsMainProd, int MainProdId, int Addons[],int len)
{
    if(IsMainProd)
        std::cout<< "Is Main Product";
    else
    {
        for(int x = 0 ; x<len;++x)
        {
          std::cout<< Addons[x];
        }
    }

    return 0 ; 
}
```