# Declaring and initializing char array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, char, initializer, list-initialization

I am trying to declare and initialize a unsigned char arr within if else block, but im seeing " cannot convert '' to 'unsigned char' in assignment" error. Can anyone please help me understand whats wrong with this? I am new to c++.

Edited:

```
unsigned char arr[4]; 
if (..){
    arr[4] = {0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F};
} else {
    arr[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
}
```

Going the below way doesn't have any issue. But I need assignment happening inside if-else so am trying to understand whats the problem with above snippet?

```
unsigned char arr[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
```

Comment: For one, that's `unsigned` not `usigned`, and then the braces around the value are wrong.

Comment: OT: `arr[8] = {0XCF};` is out of bounds. Legal indices are 0 .. 7

Comment: You may want to use `std::array<uint8_t,8> arr;` instead of `unsigned char arr[8];`

Comment: I was using unsigned in actual code. Its a typo but corrected in my question. As i said i dont have problem initializing this way unsigned char arr[8] = {0xCF} and its part of working code. If the braces are incorrect i dont think it should have worked. Let me be clear there are 8 elements im including during assignment of arr. Trying to understand braces incorrect part. Thanks

Comment: `arr[8] = {0XCF};` attempts to set the value of the 9th element in an array of size 8 to 0xCF

Comment: Conversion to unsigned char is the least of your programs, here. `char arr[8]={ ... }` is a declaration and initialization. but `arr[8]=something`, whatever the "..." assigns a value to the ninth element of the array, just like `arr[0]=something` assigns the value to the first element in the array. The problem, of course, is that there is no ninth element in an eight-element array. Any attempt to do so will result in [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). If you don't want demons flying out of your nose you should not do this.

Comment: After declaration of a variable (`arr`) anything else you do to it is no longer initialization.

Comment: This answer may help: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446883/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14446883/487892)

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that initializer syntax you are trying to use is only possible for variable declarations.

Possible solution are to declare a new array and copy it using memcpy

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
    unsigned char arr[4] =  {0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F};
    if (elsecondition){
        unsigned char arr1[4] = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
        memcpy(arr, arr1, sizeof(arr));
    }
return 0;
}
```

or to do the assignment one element at a time

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned char arr[4] =  {0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F};
    if (elsecondition){
        // we can use a loop, since all values are identical
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr); ++i)
            arr[i] = 0xFF;
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of:  `arr[4] = {0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F};` will try to assign something to the 5th element of the array (but the types are not compatible and it would be an out-of-bounds-access).

This syntax is only availble in array initialization, however `std::array` overloads `operator=` and supports what you want:

```
std::array<unsigned char, 4> arr; 
if (...){
    arr = {0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F, 0x0F};
} else {
    arr = {0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF};
}
```